# How to block incoming traffic on a virtual interface?

Tags: iptables

How do I block all incoming traffic on `eth0:0` but keep `eth0` open?

What I've tried is this:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

But this allows traffic from `eth0:0` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eth0:0` is an "alias".  It's not really a virtual network interface, it's a second IP on the same interface.

You'll have to block by using the destination IP switches for incoming traffic - specifying the IP address of the alias.  For example, assuming `eth0:0` is 10.99.99.99:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP  
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -d 10.99.99.99 -j DROP  
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```